# Why does running a LINQ query in EF Core as a split code query work but as a single query it produces casting exceptions?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

So first of all I am using EF Core 8 with .NET 8 and SQL Server

Now, if I run the following query I get an exception

```cs
properties passed in
short? hour
int? conceptNo 
int? siteNo 
DateTime startDate 
DateTime endDate

var query = DbContext.OrderSummaries.AsNoTracking();

if(siteNo.HasValue)
{
    query = query.Where(x => x.SiteNo == siteNo);
}

if (conceptNo.HasValue)
{
    query = query.Where(x => x.Site.ConceptSites.Any(y => y.ConceptNo == conceptNo));
}

if (hour.HasValue)
{
    query = query.Where(x => x.OrderHour == hour);
}

query = query.Where(x => x.OrderDate >= startDate && x.OrderDate <= endDate);

// Query split here for debugging to use quick watch
var groupedQuery = query.GroupBy(os => new { os.Site.ConceptSites.First().ConceptNo, os.Site.SiteNo, os.Site.SiteName,os.Site.SiteKey});

var finalResultQuery = groupedQuery.Select(grouped => new
            {
                ConceptNo = conceptNo ?? grouped.Key.ConceptNo,
                Date = DateTime.Now,
                Hour = (short)0,
                SiteKey = grouped.Key.SiteKey,
                SiteName = grouped.Key.SiteName,
                SiteNo = grouped.Key.SiteNo,
                AverageTime = grouped.Sum(x => x.NumStarterOrders + x.NumMainOrders + x.NumDessertOrders + x.NumDrinkOrders) != 0
                        ? (float)(grouped.Sum(x => x.SumDeliveryStarterTimes + x.SumDeliveryMainTimes + x.SumDeliveryDessertTimes + x.SumDeliveryDrinkTimes)) /
                            (grouped.Sum(x => x.NumStarterOrders + x.NumMainOrders + x.NumDessertOrders + x.NumDrinkOrders))
                        : 0,
                LongestOrderTime = grouped.Max(x => x.LongestOrderTime),
                NumOrders = grouped.Sum(x => x.NumStarterOrders + x.NumMainOrders),
                NumStarterOrders = grouped.Sum(x => x.NumStarterOrders),
                NumMainOrders = grouped.Sum(x => x.NumMainOrders),
                NumDessertOrders = grouped.Sum(x => x.NumDessertOrders),
                NumDrinkOrders = grouped.Sum(x => x.NumDrinkOrders),
                SumPrepStarterTimes = grouped.Sum(x => x.SumPrepStarterTimes),
                SumPrepMainTimes = grouped.Sum(x => x.SumPrepMainTimes),
                SumPrepDessertTimes = grouped.Sum(x => x.SumPrepDessertTimes),
                SumPrepDrinkTimes = grouped.Sum(x => x.SumPrepDrinkTimes),
                SumDeliveryStarterTimes = grouped.Sum(x => x.SumDeliveryStarterTimes),
                SumDeliveryMainTimes = grouped.Sum(x => x.SumDeliveryMainTimes),
                SumDeliveryDessertTimes = grouped.Sum(x => x.SumDeliveryDessertTimes),
                SumDeliveryDrinkTimes = grouped.Sum(x => x.SumDeliveryDrinkTimes),
                NumLateStarterOrders = grouped.Sum(x => x.NumLateStarterOrders),
                NumLateMainOrders = grouped.Sum(x => x.NumLateMainOrders),
                NumLateDessertOrders = grouped.Sum(x => x.NumLateDessertOrders),
                NumLateDrinkOrders = grouped.Sum(x => x.NumLateDrinkOrders),
                NumCheckbacks = grouped.Sum(x => x.NumCheckbacks),
                NumLateCheckbacks = grouped.Sum(x => x.NumLateCheckbacks),
                NumManualHolds = grouped.Sum(x => x.NumManualHolds),
                NumStarterItems = grouped.Sum(x => x.NumStarterItems),
                NumMainItems = grouped.Sum(x => x.NumMainItems),
                NumDessertItems = grouped.Sum(x => x.NumDessertItems),
                NumDrinkItems = grouped.Sum(x => x.NumDrinkItems),
                NumLateStarterItems = grouped.Sum(x => x.NumLateStarterItems),
                NumLateMainItems = grouped.Sum(x => x.NumLateMainItems),
                NumLateDessertItems = grouped.Sum(x => x.NumLateDessertItems),
                NumLateDrinkItems = grouped.Sum(x => x.NumLateDrinkItems),
                NumLateOrders = grouped.Sum(x => x.NumLateStarterOrders + x.NumLateMainOrders)
            });

var finalResult = finalResultQuery.ToList();
```

I get this exception from enabling SQL Logging

> fail: 09/02/2024 10:00:40.779 CoreEventId.QueryIterationFailed[10100] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query)
> An exception occurred while iterating over the results of a query for context type 'Persistence.DbContext'.
> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Int16'.
> at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.get_Int16()
> at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetInt16(Int32 i)
> at lambda_method436(Closure, QueryContext, DbDataReader, ResultContext, SingleQueryResultCoordinator)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()

But, if I split the end code query by putting `ToList()` at the end of grouped query, like so, then everything works fine.

```cs
var groupedQuery = query.GroupBy(os => new { os.Site.ConceptSites.First().ConceptNo, os.Site.SiteNo, os.Site.SiteName,os.Site.SiteKey})
.ToList();

var finalResultQuery = groupedQuery.Select(grouped => new
            {
                ConceptNo = conceptNo ?? grouped.Key.ConceptNo,
                Date = DateTime.Now,
                Hour = (short)0,
                SiteKey = grouped.Key.SiteKey,
                SiteName = grouped.Key.SiteName,
                SiteNo = grouped.Key.SiteNo,
                AverageTime = grouped.Sum(x => x.NumStarterOrders + x.NumMainOrders + x.NumDessertOrders + x.NumDrinkOrders) != 0
                        ? (float)(grouped.Sum(x => x.SumDeliveryStarterTimes + x.SumDeliveryMainTimes + x.SumDeliveryDessertTimes + x.SumDeliveryDrinkTimes)) /
                            (grouped.Sum(x => x.NumStarterOrders + x.NumMainOrders + x.NumDessertOrders + x.NumDrinkOrders))
                        : 0,
                LongestOrderTime = grouped.Max(x => x.LongestOrderTime),
                NumOrders = grouped.Sum(x => x.NumStarterOrders + x.NumMainOrders),
                NumStarterOrders = grouped.Sum(x => x.NumStarterOrders),
                NumMainOrders = grouped.Sum(x => x.NumMainOrders),
                NumDessertOrders = grouped.Sum(x => x.NumDessertOrders),
                NumDrinkOrders = grouped.Sum(x => x.NumDrinkOrders),
                SumPrepStarterTimes = grouped.Sum(x => x.SumPrepStarterTimes),
                SumPrepMainTimes = grouped.Sum(x => x.SumPrepMainTimes),
                SumPrepDessertTimes = grouped.Sum(x => x.SumPrepDessertTimes),
                SumPrepDrinkTimes = grouped.Sum(x => x.SumPrepDrinkTimes),
                SumDeliveryStarterTimes = grouped.Sum(x => x.SumDeliveryStarterTimes),
                SumDeliveryMainTimes = grouped.Sum(x => x.SumDeliveryMainTimes),
                SumDeliveryDessertTimes = grouped.Sum(x => x.SumDeliveryDessertTimes),
                SumDeliveryDrinkTimes = grouped.Sum(x => x.SumDeliveryDrinkTimes),
                NumLateStarterOrders = grouped.Sum(x => x.NumLateStarterOrders),
                NumLateMainOrders = grouped.Sum(x => x.NumLateMainOrders),
                NumLateDessertOrders = grouped.Sum(x => x.NumLateDessertOrders),
                NumLateDrinkOrders = grouped.Sum(x => x.NumLateDrinkOrders),
                NumCheckbacks = grouped.Sum(x => x.NumCheckbacks),
                NumLateCheckbacks = grouped.Sum(x => x.NumLateCheckbacks),
                NumManualHolds = grouped.Sum(x => x.NumManualHolds),
                NumStarterItems = grouped.Sum(x => x.NumStarterItems),
                NumMainItems = grouped.Sum(x => x.NumMainItems),
                NumDessertItems = grouped.Sum(x => x.NumDessertItems),
                NumDrinkItems = grouped.Sum(x => x.NumDrinkItems),
                NumLateStarterItems = grouped.Sum(x => x.NumLateStarterItems),
                NumLateMainItems = grouped.Sum(x => x.NumLateMainItems),
                NumLateDessertItems = grouped.Sum(x => x.NumLateDessertItems),
                NumLateDrinkItems = grouped.Sum(x => x.NumLateDrinkItems),
                NumLateOrders = grouped.Sum(x => x.NumLateStarterOrders + x.NumLateMainOrders)
            });

var finalResult = finalResultQuery.ToList();
```

The tables in the query I have double checked that the schema matches what I have.

Is there a way I can find out which value is causing it?

Update:
Included models but with no relevant properties stripped out

```cs
public partial class OrderSummary
{
   public short SiteNo { get; set; }

   public Site Site { get; set; } // Added navigation property

           public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
        public byte OrderHour { get; set; }
        public short NumStarterOrders { get; set; }
        public short NumMainOrders { get; set; }
        public short NumDessertOrders { get; set; }
        public short NumDrinkOrders { get; set; }
        public int SumPrepStarterTimes { get; set; }
        public int SumPrepMainTimes { get; set; }
        public int SumPrepDessertTimes { get; set; }
        public int SumPrepDrinkTimes { get; set; }
        public int SumDeliveryStarterTimes { get; set; }
        public int SumDeliveryMainTimes { get; set; }
        public int SumDeliveryDessertTimes { get; set; }
        public int SumDeliveryDrinkTimes { get; set; }
        public short NumLateStarterOrders { get; set; }
        public short NumLateMainOrders { get; set; }
        public short NumLateDessertOrders { get; set; }
        public short NumLateDrinkOrders { get; set; }
        public short NumCheckbacks { get; set; }
        public short NumLateCheckbacks { get; set; }
        public short LongestOrderTime { get; set; }
        public short NumStarterItems { get; set; }
        public short NumMainItems { get; set; }
        public short NumDessertItems { get; set; }
        public short NumDrinkItems { get; set; }
        public short NumLateStarterItems { get; set; }
        public short NumLateMainItems { get; set; }
        public short NumLateDessertItems { get; set; }
        public short NumLateDrinkItems { get; set; }
        public short NumManualHolds { get; set; }
        public short NumLatePrepStarterOrders { get; set; }
        public short NumLatePrepMainOrders { get; set; }
        public short NumLatePrepDessertOrders { get; set; }
        public short NumLatePrepStarterItems { get; set; }
        public short NumLatePrepMainItems { get; set; }
        public short NumLatePrepDessertItems { get; set; }
}

public partial class Site
{
   public short SiteNo { get; set; }

   public string SiteName { get; set; } = null!;
   
   public Guid SiteKey { get; set; }

   // .. other properties

   public ICollection<ConceptSite> ConceptSites { get; set; } // Added navigation property

   public ICollection<OrderSummary> OrderSummaries { get; set; } // Added navigation property
}

public partial class Concept
{
   public short ConceptNo { get; set; }   
    
   // .. other properties

   public ICollection<ConceptSite> ConceptSites { get; set; } // Added navigation property
}

public partial class ConceptSite
{
   [Column(TypeName = "int")] // Added because table schemea is int but Concept and Site Entities use short
   public short ConceptNo { get; set; }
   public Concept Concept { get;set;} // Added navigation property

   [Column(TypeName = "int")] // Added because table schemea is int but Concept and Site Entities use short
   public short SiteNo { get; set; }
   public Site Site { get; set; }        // Added navigation property
}
```

Comment: The real question is why are you trying to write SQL in LINQ instead of using proper entities and relations? That's what's causing the problems. EF is an ORM that deals with entities and relations, not tables and rows. LINQ is just the language used by that ORM to query *the entities*, not the tables. There shouldn't be any explicit JOINs in the LINQ query, those are generated automatically by EF itself based on the entity relations, eg `Site.Concepts`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos So your saying that what I want to achieve cannot be done in EF?
The database is old, I have not control over modifying it so the relationships have not been set correctly and I cant do things like DbContext.OrderSummaries.Include(x => x.Sites).Include(x => x.ConceptSites) etc etc

Comment: Just to add, I also tried with Query expression and it produced the same result.

Comment: I imagine how this query is ineffective. `grouped.First()` is a performance killer. Repeated several times it produces terrible SQL.

Comment: Show your model classes, this query can be rewritten.

Comment: I'm saying *the code* and the way it treats EF is wrong, not EF. Doing what you want is actually quite easy in EF if you use it properly. There's no need for `.Join(DbContext.Sites,`, use `OrderSummaries.Site` or `OrderSummaries.Sites`, depending on the type of relation. There's no need for ` (joinResult.cs.ConceptNo == conceptNo || conceptNo == null) &&` at all. You can easily append `AND` clauses with eg `if(conceptNo!=null) { query=query.Where(c=>c.Site.Concept.ConceptNo=conceptNo)`. I suspect by that point you don't even need that `GroupBy` to eliminate the duplicates caused by the JOINs

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos OrderSummaries does not have a navigation property of Site, so I can't. Or can I write the class with the property even though the database itself does not have this relation?

Comment: Which means there are no nested joins to begin with, they're an artifact of the code. Yes, EF will generate JOINs but it will also use the mapping info to reconstruct the object hierarchy from the repeated values *without* resorting to grouping. `grouped.First()` will also be eliminated since it seems to map to an `OrderSummary.Site` property.

Comment: @Gaz83 `does not have a navigation property of Site,` add it. That's the source of the problem. `the database itself does not have this relation?` FKs are constraints, not relations. They ensure that the value in a column exists in another table. EF doesn't care whether the constraints exist or not. When you specify the relation either through attributes or the fluent API you specify entities and columns, not FK names

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos added navigation properties (see Update) still an issue.

Comment: Stop posting bad queries. If you want to make it work, think in SQL first. Will prepare answer soon.

Comment: As I read the error then it get some data out fine, but can't place it in the model. I would try 1 by 1 to replace shorts with ints, and see if one of them work and then take it from there. Maybe hour?

Comment: and also instead of just adding debug then fire up profiler from SQL Server and see the SQL and run it yourself

Comment: @ThomasKoelle If you mean by run the generated SQL query in SQL server, tried that and it works fine. Also in my query, if I do `.Select(grouped => new { // properties })` surly then its fitting it to a dynamic model?

Comment: a quick way to see datatypes is make it into an sql view and expand columns. You are looking for something that comes out as an int, but where your model is a short.

Comment: @ThomasKoelle thats very helpful, I will take a look now

Comment: The new code shows clear bugs - `short` (Int16) properties are mapped to `int` (Int32) columns. The error complains about casting an `int` to a `short`. Try changing all `short` properties to `int`. The `Where` clause is still a problem. If you don't want a condition, don't include it at all. You don't have to build the query in a single statement.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The where clause is required to filter what I don't want. I have now modified my code to dynamically build the query and still the same result. The only class that has the wrong types is `ConceptSite` which uses `int` instead of `short`. I never set the table up and I cannot change it. I imagine I would get new issues with changing shorts to `int` such as inserting an `int` value into `smallint` in SQL

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Also changing the end of the query to this `query = query.Where(x => x.OrderDate >= startDate && x.OrderDate <= endDate); var selectedItems = query.Include(x => x.Site)
                .ThenInclude(x => x.ConceptSites.Take(1))
                .ToList();`

Works fine so the `int` `short` properties on `ConceptSite` are not the issue.

Comment: Would love to know why the negative vote!

Comment: Can you show other properties? I've messed up with Method chain syntax and cannot understand from where they come in query.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I have added all properties that are relevant and are used either in the `where` clause or `select`

Comment: This grouping by `os.Site.ConceptSites.First()` is really strange. You never can tell which `ConceptSite` will actually be first. It's even possible that if `conceptNo` is entered as a predicate you'll see results *without* this `conceptNo`! (Because it exists, but is not the first.) This, and all the above, makes me suspect that you need to rethink if this query really does what it's supposed to do.

Comment: @GertArnold yeah.... I have already been over this with me my colleagues so don't even go there. But you are correct, you don't know what it will return. Seems acceptable so....

Answer (score 0):

It is not final variant, but is closer. Probably I do not understand what this query do and why you have put `First` in every query.

```cs
var query = DbContext.OrderSummaries.AsQueryable();

if (siteNo.HasValue)
{
    query = query.Where(x => x.SiteNo == siteNo);
}

if (conceptNo.HasValue)
{
    query = query.Where(x => x.Site.ConceptSites.Any(y => y.ConceptNo == conceptNo));
}

if (hour.HasValue)
{
    query = query.Where(x => x.OrderHour == hour);
}

query = query.Where(x => x.OrderDate >= startDate && x.OrderDate <= endDate);

var resultQuery = 
    from os in query
    from cs in os.Site.ConceptSites
    group new { os, cs }  by new 
    {
        cs.Concept.ConceptNo,
        os.SiteNo,
        os.Site.SiteName,
        os.Site.SiteKey
    } into g
    select new
    {
        ConceptNo = g.Key.ConceptNo,
        Date = DateTime.Now,
        Hour = (short)0,
        SiteKey = g.Key.SiteKey,
        SiteName = g.Key.SiteName,
        SiteNo = (short)g.Key.SiteNo,
        AverageTime = g.Sum(x => x.so.NumStarterOrders + x.so.NumMainOrders + x.so.NumDessertOrders + x.so.NumDrinkOrders) != 0
                        ? (float)(g.Sum(x => x.so.SumDeliveryStarterTimes + x.so.SumDeliveryMainTimes + x.so.SumDeliveryDessertTimes + x.so.SumDeliveryDrinkTimes)) /
                            (g.Sum(x => x.so.NumStarterOrders + x.so.NumMainOrders + x.so.NumDessertOrders + x.so.NumDrinkOrders))
                        : 0
        LongestOrderTime = g.Max(x => x.os.LongestOrderTime),
        NumOrders = g.Sum(x => x.os.NumStarterOrders + x.os.NumMainOrders),
        NumStarterOrders = g.Sum(x => (int)x.os.NumStarterOrders),
        NumMainOrders = g.Sum(x => (int)x.os.NumMainOrders),
        NumDessertOrders = g.Sum(x => (int)x.os.NumDessertOrders),
        NumDrinkOrders = g.Sum(x => (int)x.os.NumDrinkOrders),
        SumPrepStarterTimes = g.Sum(x => x.os.SumPrepStarterTimes),
        SumPrepMainTimes = g.Sum(x => x.os.SumPrepMainTimes),
        SumPrepDessertTimes = g.Sum(x => x.os.SumPrepDessertTimes),
        SumPrepDrinkTimes = g.Sum(x => x.os.SumPrepDrinkTimes),
        SumDeliveryStarterTimes = g.Sum(x => x.os.SumDeliveryStarterTimes),
        SumDeliveryMainTimes = g.Sum(x => x.os.SumDeliveryMainTimes),
        SumDeliveryDessertTimes = g.Sum(x => x.os.SumDeliveryDessertTimes),
        SumDeliveryDrinkTimes = g.Sum(x => x.os.SumDeliveryDrinkTimes),
        NumLateStarterOrders = g.Sum(x => (int)x.os.NumLateStarterOrders),
        NumLateMainOrders = g.Sum(x => (int)x.os.NumLateMainOrders),
        NumLateDessertOrders = g.Sum(x => (int)x.os.NumLateDessertOrders),
        NumLateDrinkOrders = g.Sum(x => (int)x.os.NumLateDrinkOrders),
        NumCheckbacks = g.Sum(x => (int)x.os.NumCheckbacks),
        NumLateCheckbacks = g.Sum(x => (int)x.os.NumLateCheckbacks),
        NumManualHolds = g.Sum(x => (int)x.os.NumManualHolds),
        NumStarterItems = g.Sum(x => (int)x.os.NumStarterItems),
        NumMainItems = g.Sum(x => (int)x.os.NumMainItems),
        NumDessertItems = g.Sum(x => (int)x.os.NumDessertItems),
        NumDrinkItems = g.Sum(x => (int)x.os.NumDrinkItems),
        NumLateStarterItems = g.Sum(x => (int)x.os.NumLateStarterItems),
        NumLateMainItems = g.Sum(x => (int)x.os.NumLateMainItems),
        NumLateDessertItems = g.Sum(x => (int)x.os.NumLateDessertItems),
        NumLateDrinkItems = g.Sum(x => (int)x.os.NumLateDrinkItems),
        NumLateOrders = g.Sum(x => (int)(x.os.NumLateStarterOrders + x.os.NumLateMainOrders))
    };

var result = resultQuery
    .ToList();
```

Comment: I will try it out. When you say I put First in every query, I have only put it in once place, which I can explain why

Comment: It makes m crazy that I do not understand what this query should do. And I really do not understand :)

Comment: Ok so there is a table which has `OrderSummary` . I need to get all the `OrderSummary` where the Order date falls between 2 given dates and with the option to match the following parameters. Match the `OrderHour` (hour parameter), the SiteNo (siteNo parameter) and if the OrderSummary.Site.ConceptSite has a matching ConceptNo (conceptNo parameter). This query would return many rows. It then needs grouping by `SiteNo` to get all the `OrderSummary` by site. We then want 1 OrderSummary per site which sums all the values. Hope that makes sense?

Comment: Oh and I tried your query, same result.

Comment: To make it clear with the grouping. Lets say `20 OrderSummary` is returned and all have the same `SiteNo`, which they can. We group these and then we summarize into a NEW `Ordersummary`. So if all `20  OrderSummary` had `NumOrders = 10` then we should end up with 1 `OrderSummary`  with `NumOrders = 200`